# How to improve MySQL query with JOINED tables and ORDER BY and OFFSET

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-order-by, query-performance

`games_releases` is a table that combines game information. Infos like a game title, the game publisher or developer are the same for many different games, so they are saved in different tables that are later joined together.

The example below only joins the `games_titles` table for easier understanding (but in reality there are a few more tables joined following the same principle).

The `games_releases` table:

```
id            int(11)     <- unique
title_id      int(11)     <- index
developer_id  int(11)
... more game relevant data
```

Some typical rows of `games_releases` would look like:

```
id    title_id   developer_id   ...    ...
--------------------------------------------
1     17         265
2     23         41
3     31         3
4     42         15
5     17         123
```

The `games_titles` table:

```
id      int(11)       <- unique
title   varchar(128)
created int(11)
```

Some typical rows of `games_titles` would look like:

```
id    title     created
----------------------------------------
17    Pac-Man   [some unix timestamp]   
23    Defender  [some unix timestamp]
31    Scramble  [some unix timestamp]
42    Q*bert    [some unix timestamp]
99    Phoenix   [some unix timestamp]
```

NOW: Let's assume a user wants to see all games in alphabetical order (24 at a time), then this query would be executed...

```
SELECT
    id AS release_id, t.`title` AS title
FROM
    games_releases

LEFT JOIN games_titles t ON t.`id`=`games_releases`.`title_id`
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 24
```

This would be returned

```
release_id    title
-----------------------------
2             Defender
1             Pac-Man
5             Pac-Man
4             Q*Bert
3             Scramble
```

So basically the resulting table features the strings rather the ids.

The challenge: This query will take 0.2 seconds to run which is way to slow (`games_releases` has around 80.000 items listed, but imagine the database grows to 1.000.000 items).

Here is what explain tells me (games_releases has an index title_id):

```
id select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  games_releases  NULL    index   NULL    title_id    4   NULL    76669   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   phoenix.games_releases.title_id 1
```

Any chance to optimize this?

EDIT: The question has been answered. A wrong "LEFT JOIN" instead of "JOIN" was the problem.

But: What would I do to conquer longer execution times with growing OFFSET?

Although having read loads about it, I struggle to understand how to set indexes efficiently when doing multiple JOIN.

Having a "title" index for games_titles does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: could be that games_releases adn game_titles don't match ???

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay special attention to the section on query optimization. Then please [edit] your question to provide more information, so we can help you. By the way, the MySQL query planner treats views as subqueries, so optimizing a view doesn't guarantee the outer query will be optimized.

Comment: @O.Jones I think I did this already. There is the query in question and the EXPLAIN. I will ad the db structure.

Comment: Right. It's important to see the indexes and data types.

Comment: @O.Jones: Done. I really tried to put it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: questions about query performance generally **must** present the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` of each table involved in the query. Table structure makes a difference to performance.

It looks, from your query, like you want to show the first 24 titles, alphabetically, from the `games_titles` table where there's any match at all in the `games_releases` table. I don't understand the logic of your `LEFT JOIN` though. Do you want the titles repeated if there's more than one row for the title in `games_releases`?  What do you want done with rows in `games_releases` that are unmatched by rows in `games_titles`?

I think you can get the result you want as follows:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title
     FROM games_titles t
     JOIN games_releases r ON t.id = r.title_id
    ORDER BY t.title
    LIMIT 24
```

This gives distinct rows from your titles table matching anything in the releases table. This will probably be optimal in its performance. I wonder, though, what is significant about the first 24 titles, alphabetically, in your application, and why that is important to put into a view.

`SELECT lots, of, stuff .... ORDER BY something LIMIT number` is a notorious performance antipattern. Why? MySQL has to sort lots of data, only to discard a small amount of it. The limitations of view definition make it hard for you to do something more efficient in a view.

You didn't tell us whether `games_titles.id` is indexed. It needs to be indexed. If it's the primary key it is indexed.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The purpose is: The table games_releases has many rows which reference other tables (normalizing). What I want is to get SELECT from games_releases in alphabetical order. So I want to fetch the rows from games_releases, NOT from games_titles. The games_releases row has all the information about a game, games_titles only has the name of a game. So there could be 100 releases with the same name that just reference the games_title table to fetch the name of the release. I explain better in my next edit.

Comment: I have done my best to explain it better in the question. I would be very grateful if you gave it another look ...

Comment: Replacing the left join with an inner join (and adding an index on title column of course) should persuade MySQL to flip the order of the tables and process this fast.

Comment: I am checking this at the moment.

Comment: This helped a lot, @peufeu! I don't know why I used LEFT JOIN at all! But then again I am not that great in mysql (as you can tell by now). Thanks so much. Now I need to find a way to make it faster when there is big OFFSET. google is my friend!